# PostgreSQL: how to dump foreign data

Tags: postgresql, dump, foreign-data-wrapper

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 and foreign tables.

Now I need to dump data from the foreign tables by Postgres.
I got only definition of foreign tables, using **pg_dump**, but not data.

Can you help me to find out how to do this - dump foreign data?

p.s. I can do `select * from <foreign table>` by **psql** and put this data into file, but this produce incredible file format, which has good human-visible representation but it hard to operate automatically this data and more other problems.

Comment: You can use `copy` (or for a client side file: `\copy` in `psql`) to generate a text file with the data

Comment: Thanx a lot, `copy` is much better, but still not the actual thing I want. I can't just copy table, because it is foreign - it is allowed to `copy (select * ...`. As a result I want to get an sql (for example as the result of pg_dump normal table).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. copy is excellent method. Thanx a lot!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
In this case I think documentation is misleading. It says that `table` includes views, foreign tables, etc. But in fact it does the opposite. Only basic **heap** tables are exported.

`--table=table`
Dump only tables with names matching table. For this purpose, “table” includes >views, materialized views, sequences, and foreign tables.